# Can't pass to onclick in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

look at the following angular directive:

```
angular.module("mySystem").directive("pageFooter", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: { footerhref: '&' },
        template: <button onclick="{{footerhref}}">{{footerhref}}</button>
    }
});

<page-footer footerhref="location.href='\Home.html'" />
```

Could somebody tell me why the footerhref doesn't pass through into the onclick but it does for the button content? (I don't want it in the content. I've just added that an example).

And is this possible to fix?

If I just create a button like below it works:

```
 <button onclick="location.href = '\Home.html'">Using onclick without Angular</button>
```

This is how I'm trying to get the angular directive to render.

Comment: `onclick` expects a function call and not an expression that resolves to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick` expects a function call and not an expression that resolves to a string.

You would have to use `&` instead of `@` since we are passing in a executable line of code rather than a string.

You will have to use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`. The reason why `onclick` will not work, based on the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nodomevents) is:

> Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please
>   use the ng- versions (such as ng-click instead of onclick) instead.

Also, change `templateUrl` to `template` since you are providing the template inline

You will have to set the location reference in the $scope since you are trying to access `location` from the UI markup `<page-footer footerhref="location.href='\Home.html'" />`

[Here is a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TNC2wyttllFNcafKAzU9?p=preview).

```
app.directive("pageFooter", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: { footerhref: '&', caption: '@' },
        template: '<button ng-click="footerhref()">{{caption}}</button>'
    }
});

<page-footer footerhref="location.href='\Home.html'" caption="Home"></page-footer>

$scope.location = location; // In your controller
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want the string 'location.href='/Home' in my onclick. I'm aware it's not a method call. If I just create a button like this: <button onclick="location.href='\index.html'">Back</button> it navigates me back to the index page. So I do want that string value.

Comment: When you use `@` and pass in `location.href='/Home'`, that will be considered as a string and not an executable line of code. Which is why you need to use `&` instead.

Comment: If you want both the string `'Home'` and the executable code `location.href='/Home'` to be passed in, you will have to send them in through separate attribute bindings. One would be bound using `@` and the other with `&`. I've edited my answer to include the option to send in the button caption.

Comment: OK, I get what you're trying to say (I think). I've updated the footerhref = "&". But in the onclick I still don't get the string 'location.href...'. I know you're saying it expects an executable line of code but how come it works for the button in my comment above? Does that make sense? Thank btw.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working plunker. I understand your problem. You are trying to pass in a string into the onclick() function so that when it gets rendered, it looks like `onclick(location.href='/Home')`. The reason this does not work is that `onclick` itself is not supported (I've mentioned the reason in my updated answer) So, to get this to work, we need to use `ng-click`. But, for `ng-click` to work, we will have to use `&`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help and explanations